# Seach a directory for a file that fits a filemask, search it line by line for specific text and return that line

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

In Python, its the vagueness that I struggle with.

Lets start with what I know. I know that I want to search a specific directory for a file. And I want to search that file for a specific line that contains a specific string, and return only that line.

Which brings me to what I don't know. I have a vague description of the specific filename:
`some_file_{variable}_{somedatestamp}_{sometimestamp}.log`
So I know the file will start with `some_file` followed by a known variable and ending in `.log`. I don't know the date stamp or the time stamp. And to top it off, the file might not still exist at the time of searching, so I need to cover for that eventuality.

To better describe the problem, I have the line of the BASH script that accomplishes this:
`ls -1tr /dir/some_file_${VARIABLE}_*.log | tail -2 | xargs -I % grep "SEARCH STRING" %`

So basically, I want to recreate that line of code from the BASH script in Python, and throw a message in the case that the search returns no files.

Comment: Break this down into smaller parts and solve each part. For example, the first step is to get a list of files in a directory. If I were doing this, I'd just print those out. Then I'd go from there to figure out the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variant of this will work.  This will work for an arbitrary folder structure and will search all subfolders....  results will hold path to directory, filename, and txt, line number (1-based).

Some key pieces:

- `os.walk` is beautiful for searching directory trees.  The `top=` can be relative or absolute
- use a context manager `with ... as ...`  to open files as it closes them automatically
- python iterates over text-based files in line-by line format

#### Code

```
from os import walk, path

magic_text = 'lucky charms'
results = []

for dirpath, _, filenames in walk(top='.'):
    for f in filenames:
        # check the name.  can use string methods or indexing...
        if f.startswith('some_name') and f[-4:] == '.log':
            # read the lines and look for magic text
            with open(path.join(dirpath, f), 'r') as src:
                # if you iterate over a file, it returns line-by-line
                for idx, line in enumerate(src):
                    # strings support the "in" operator...
                    if magic_text in line:
                        results.append((dirpath, f, idx+1, line))

for item in results:
    print(f'on path {item[0]} in file {item[1]} on line {item[2]} found: {item[3]}')
```

In a trivial folder tree, I placed the magic words in one file and got this result:

```
on path ./subfolder/subsub in file some_name_331a.log on line 2 found: lucky charms are delicious
```

Comment: As my only goal was to return the line from the mystery file that contained the magic_text, I modified it a bit. Which is a good thing because `print(f` wasn't supported in my version of Python.

But the bottom line is that you produced the code solution. Thanks so much for your help. And especially for commenting and explaining your code so well that I learned more Python along the way.

Cheers!

Comment: OK, great.  Given the fact that there are at least 53 ways in python to format strings with data, "f-strings" are ancient history, and if your version doesn't support that, you are definitely using a version of python that is beyond end-of-life and is not being updated.  You should move up.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
from glob import glob
import os

log_dir = 'C:\\Apps\\MyApp\\logs\\'

log_variable = input("Enter variable:")
filename = "some_file"+log_variable

# Option 1
searched_files1 = glob(log_dir+filename+'*.log')
print(f'Total files found = {len(searched_files1)}')
print(searched_files1)


# Option 2
searched_files2 = []
for object in os.listdir(log_dir):
    if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(log_dir,object)) and object.startswith(filename) and object.endswith('.log')):
        searched_files2.append(object)
print(f'Total files found = {len(searched_files2)}')
print(searched_files2)
```

Comment: Option 2 is close. That should find the file that fits the file mask I'm looking for.

However, once it finds a file with the correct file mask, I need to search that file line by line for the search string. If it finds the search string, then I need to print that line to the screen. If it doesn't find the search string, it should continue to look for other files that fit the file mask and search them as well.

Unfortunately its also possible the search will find no files that fit the file mask. Or find multiple files that fit the file mask but don't contain the search string.